# how to style this bottombar with custompaint flutter

Tags: flutter

path . arc To Point(Offset(size .width * 0.60, 10), radius: Radius .circular(10,), clockwise: false, );

Hi, I am trying to style this bottom bar but the place where floating action button is placed, is not getting designed according to UI, how can I do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Jmn.jpg)

Comment: you cannot use `arcTo` as the path you want to get is not a part of a circle, instead you need to use either `quadTo` or `cubicTo`

Comment: and how can i set x,y here as i want to draw an uspide trainagle with a slop shape

Comment: x,y of what point?

Comment: here is code,, Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height-65); // Start
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.50, 0, size.width * 0.35,5);//from left to top right
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.40, 0, size.width * 0.40, 20);
    //path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.60, 10), radius: Radius.circular(10,), clockwise: false, );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.60, 5, size.width * 0.61, 5);//from right to to left
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.60, 0, size.width, 15);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

Comment: i don't understand where should i make changes in order to get that shape